# Merging JSON with array to create new file

Tags: json, dictionary, join, mapbox, jq

I am trying to make a map of the U.S. with Mapbox that shows median home price by county. I have a .json file that contains all the counties and is already accepted by Mapbox tileset -

```
{
  "type": "Topology",
  "transform": {
    "scale": [
      0.035896170617061705,
      0.005347309530953095
    ],
    "translate": [
      -179.14734,
      17.884813
    ]
  },
  "objects": {
    "us_counties_20m": {
      "type": "GeometryCollection",
      "geometries": [
        {
          "type": "Polygon",
          "arcs": [],
          "id": "0500000US01001"
        },
        {
          "type": "Polygon",
          "arcs": [],
          "id": "0500000US01009"
        },
        {
          "type": "Polygon",
          "arcs": [],
          "id": "0500000US01017"
        },
        {
          "type": "Polygon",
          "arcs": [],
          "id": "0500000US01021"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Basically, it's a json file with "type" (Polygon), "arcs" (to map the county), and "id", which is an ID for the county.

This is great and accepted by Mapbox Tilesets to give me a visualization by county, but I need to add in median home price by county (in order to get colors by county, based on price).

I have a second json file that is more like an array, which has

```
[
  {
    "0500000US01001": 51289.0,
    "0500000US01009": 46793.0,
    "0500000US01017": 39857.0,
    "0500000US01021": 48859.0
  }
]
```

and so on, but basically it has the ID -> median home price per county. **The ID's are the same between these 2 files, and of the same quantity.** So I need get a 3rd json file out of these, which has "type", "arcs", "id", and "PRICE" (the addition).

These files are huge - any suggestions? I tried using jq but received an error that

```
jq: error ... object ({"type":"To...) and array ([{"0500000U...) cannot be multiplied
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here's a link to the first JSON - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-visualization/folium/master/examples/data/us_counties_20m_topo.json

Comment: and a link to the second JSON - https://gist.githubusercontent.com/wrobstory/5609959/raw/57816267db7aad5e826d6f47f12be97848cc7f40/data3.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straightforward approach would be saving the second file into a variable and using it as a reference while updating the first file. E.g:

```
jq 'add as $prices | input
| .objects.us_counties_20m.geometries[] |= . + {PRICE: $prices[.id]}' file2 file1
```

`add` can be substituted with `.[0]` if the array in `file2` contains only one object.

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/MHypDS-C64)</sup>

Comment: Wow! This is amazing. Thanks for including the online demo too - that really helped. I used the code above and I got exactly what I wanted to show up. I'm going to now copy-paste that code into a new JSON - thanks so much!

Comment: @Galen just redirect JQ's output to a file, like `jq '...' file2 file1 > file3`

Comment: There just seems to be a small issue with Mapbox - I would like my data to be like this, with a "properties" section: https://docs.mapbox.com/help/demos/choropleth-studio-gl/stateData.geojson     Is there a way to manipulate my new file3 into something like this, with "properties"? https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/choropleth-studio-gl-pt-1/

Comment: For instance, the "properties" in the choropleth json file above are "name" and "density", which mapbox picked up because they were grouped in "properties". I would like my "properties" to contain the data in file2 (PRICE).

Comment: @Galen I don't know anything about Mapbox. If you need help with transforming JSON, I think I (and others who follow the [tag:jq] tag) can help, but you need to describe the task clearly, provide input/output samples and show what you've tried for yourself. Besides comments section is not a good place to ask further questions.

Comment: Would it be possible, when joining file2 and file1 together, to put file2's PRICE into another dictionary? For instance, instead of just "PRICE", I would have "properties":{"PRICE": 12345}. Can this "wrapping" of PRICE be done, either before or after your previous accepted answer? Thanks!

Comment: @Galen If I'm not missing anything, instead of `. + {PRICE: ...}`, you can use `. + {properties: {PRICE: ...}}` to do that

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you so much!! @oguz ismail

Comment: @GalenBlueTalon, while jq's solution is great and fun, I offer also (so just you're aware of alternatives) to look at the `jtc` (I'm the creator of the tool). With `jtc`, the solution looks like this: `jtc -w'<id>l:<Id>v[-1]' -i median.json -i'[0]>Id<t' -T'{"PRICE":{{}}}' maps.json`. If if you like to apply changes right into the file, then add flag `-f`.